# Cropping an image based on its angles with PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a python script where the program shows an image that contains a rectangle or a square and then the End-user should specify four angles of this shape by drag some pointers on its angles. These pointers will be presented by the program.

Based on these angles the program should crop the shape from the rest of the image.

- Example of images that the program will show:

[image] 
[image]

- Pointers Images:

[image]

- What the user should do :

[image]

- The Output of the program:

[image]

How I can do this? 
I'm Working with **Python3**, **PyQt5**.

This is what I have done so far, which is the process of allowing the user to browse to select an image from his computer and upload it to the program

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.setEnabled(True)
        Dialog.resize(1050, 800)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 800))
        Dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1050, 800))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("project pic/images LPR icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);\n"
"background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);")
        self.UserImageLbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.UserImageLbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 60, 800, 600))
        self.UserImageLbl.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.UserImageLbl.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.UserImageLbl.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.UserImageLbl.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.UserImageLbl.setLineWidth(1)
        self.UserImageLbl.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.UserImageLbl.setText("")
        self.UserImageLbl.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("project pic/upn.png"))
        self.UserImageLbl.setScaledContents(False)
        self.UserImageLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.UserImageLbl.setObjectName("UserImageLbl")
        self.BrowesImageButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 690, 230, 60))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(230, 60))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(230, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setFont(font)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 214, 157);\n"
"background-color: rgb(0, 170, 127);")
        self.BrowesImageButton.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
       # self.BrowesImageButton.setStyleSheet("BrowesImageButton:hover { background-color:  rgb(0, 214, 157) }" )

        self.BrowesImageButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.BrowesImageButton.setObjectName("BrowesImageButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        self.BrowesImageButton.clicked.connect(self.setImage)


    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", " Cropping Shapes"))
        self.BrowesImageButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Browse Image"))


    def setImage(self):
        #fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.bmp);;All Files (*)") # Ask for file
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png)") # Ask for file

        if fileName: # If the user gives a file
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName) # Setup pixmap with the provided image
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.UserImageLbl.width(), self.UserImageLbl.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio) # Scale pixmap
            self.UserImageLbl.setPixmap(pixmap) # Set the pixmap onto the label
            self.UserImageLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) # Align the label to center


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried even if it doesn't work? as you should know SO not a SW service

Comment: I have done working on the process of allowing the user to browse to select an image from his computer and upload it to the program. I'm stuck now with the rest which I explained in my question.

Comment: again: show what you tried

Comment: I have update my question with what I have done, thank you.

Comment: Should the cropping region always be a rectangular region parallel to the edges of the screen? If so it would be enough with 2 points, otherwise the points can be of an indefinite amount and only the polygonal region would be cut?

Comment: The cropping region will be based on the angles that the user will specify by the pointers, so based on 4 points. Thank you so much for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is better to use QGraphicsView as it allows us to add other images without the need to scale the image. In the QGraphicsView you get the points where you click on the item that has the image, and then with that information using [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714969/6622587) you get the following:

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
point_filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "41uu2.png")


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(), parent)
        self.pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.pixmap_item.setShapeMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem.BoundingRectShape)

        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def set_image(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.fitInView(self.pixmap_item, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)


class CropView(GraphicsView):
    resultChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.point_items = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.pixmap_item.pixmap().isNull():
            sp = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            lp = self.pixmap_item.mapFromScene(sp)
            if self.pixmap_item.contains(lp):
                size = QtCore.QSize(30, 30)
                height = (
                    self.mapToScene(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), size))
                    .boundingRect()
                    .size()
                    .height()
                )
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(point_filename)
                point_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap, self.pixmap_item)
                point_item.setOffset(
                    -QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), pixmap.size()).center()
                )
                point_item.setPos(lp)
                scale = height / point_item.boundingRect().size().height()
                point_item.setScale(scale)
                self.point_items.append(point_item)
                if len(self.point_items) == 4:
                    points = []
                    for it in self.point_items:
                        points.append(it.pos().toPoint())
                    self.crop(points)
                elif len(self.point_items) == 5:
                    for it in self.point_items[:-1]:
                        self.scene().removeItem(it)
                    self.point_items = [self.point_items[-1]]
            else:
                print("outside")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def crop(self, points):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714969/6622587
        polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF(points)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addPolygon(polygon)

        source = self.pixmap_item.pixmap()

        r = path.boundingRect().toRect().intersected(source.rect())

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(source.size())
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), source, source.rect())
        painter.end()
        result = pixmap.copy(r)
        self.resultChanged.emit(result)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(1050, 600)

        self.left_view = CropView()
        self.rigth_view = GraphicsView()

        self.left_view.resultChanged.connect(self.rigth_view.set_image)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Browse Image"))
        button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 214, 157);")
        button.setFixedSize(230, 60)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        button.setFont(font)
        button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button.clicked.connect(self.load_image)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.left_view, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.rigth_view, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(button, 1, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def load_image(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png)"
        )
        if fileName:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
            self.left_view.set_image(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your code and this what I got as an output: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/12/5/be634fb46c12e973e1670062772f57d2-full.png    , is there any way to connect these pointers first and then cropping the connected region. I'm new in pyqt :( .

Comment: @Sara You have to click in order, if you do it in disorder then another type of figure is generated, that is topleft -> topright -> bottomright -> bottomleft. Please avoid pointing out that you are new to PyQt that is irrelevant.

Comment: I got it, thank so much for your help. It works now.