# Correct orientation of an image based on 4 Qpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, rotation, pyqt5

I'm trying to correct orientation (rotating) of an image based on four Qpoints which was taken from the user. I found a similar code to which I work on and it was posted as a solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176013/cropping-an-image-based-on-its-angles-with-pyqt).

**The code:**

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
point_filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "Lastout.png")

class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(), parent)
        self.pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.pixmap_item.setShapeMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem.BoundingRectShape)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def set_image(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmap_item.setPixmap(pixmap)
        #The pixmap is scaled to a rectangle as small as possible outside size, preserving the aspect ratio.
        self.fitInView(self.pixmap_item, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

class CropView(GraphicsView):
    Changed_view = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.point_items = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.pixmap_item.pixmap().isNull():
            sp = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            #print("Event position = " +str(sp))
            lp = self.pixmap_item.mapFromScene(sp)
            #print("Event position FromScene = " +str(lp))
            if self.pixmap_item.contains(lp):
                size = QtCore.QSize(30, 30)
                height = (
                    self.mapToScene(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), size))
                    .boundingRect()
                    .size()
                    .height()
                )
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(point_filename)
                point_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap, self.pixmap_item)
                point_item.setOffset(
                    -QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), pixmap.size()).center()
                )
                point_item.setPos(lp)
                scale = height / point_item.boundingRect().size().height()
               # print ("Scale: "+str(scale))
                point_item.setScale(scale)
                self.point_items.append(point_item)
                if len(self.point_items) == 4:
                    points = []
                    for it in self.point_items:
                        points.append(it.pos().toPoint())
                        print ("points: " + str (it.pos().toPoint()))
                        print (" x " + str(it.x()) +" y "+ str( it.y()) )
                    self.crop(points)
                elif len(self.point_items) == 5:
                    for it in self.point_items[:-1]:
                        self.scene().removeItem(it)
                    self.point_items = [self.point_items[-1]]
            else:
                print("outside")
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def crop(self, points):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714969/6622587
        polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF(points)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addPolygon(polygon)
        source = self.pixmap_item.pixmap()
        r = path.boundingRect().toRect().intersected(source.rect())
        print (str(r))
        #t = QtGui.QTransform()  #added
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(source.size())
        #t.translate (pixmap._center.x() -pixmap.width() / 2, pixmap._center.y() -pixmap.height() / 2)
        #t.translate(pixmap.width() / 2, pixmap.height() / 2)
        # t.rotate(45.0)
        #t.translate(-pixmap.width() / 2, -pixmap.height() / 2)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), source, source.rect())
        painter.end()
        result = pixmap.copy(r)
        self.Changed_view.emit(result)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(1200, 700)
        self.left_view = CropView()
        self.rigth_view = GraphicsView()
        self.left_view.Changed_view.connect(self.rigth_view.set_image)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("Select Image"))
        button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 100, 100);")
        button.setFixedSize(230, 60)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Microsoft YaHei UI")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        button.setFont(font)
        button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        button.clicked.connect(self.load_image)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.left_view, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.rigth_view, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(button, 1, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def load_image(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *jpeg *.bmp)"
        )
        if fileName:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
            self.left_view.set_image(pixmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected output:** 
A corrected orientation of user input image after cropping

[image: A corrected orientation of user input image after cropping]

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The question which links aims to select a quadrangular region, not necessarily a rectangular region. Considering the above, the orientation of a quadrangular region is not well defined unlike a rectangular region. So using the link code without establishing more limitations means that there is no solution for your case. Could you explain your objective better without taking the link code as a basis?

Comment: I'm implementing a solution similar to the problem presented on this link, where the user selects an image then identify the angles of a something in the image such as a license plate and mostly will be in a rectangle shape. However, I need to correct the orientation of this image after cropping it by taking benefit of the specified angles (top-left> top-right > bottom-right > bottom-left ) in orientation correction. Thank you so much for your help, I usually see your name in most of the posts regarding pyqt and its really helpful.

Comment: I’m using same code to this code presented in my question (mouse event +cropping). I really need a help in correcting rotation point . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting four arbitrary points will not give you a rectangle, but a quadrilateral, which might not have all corners with 90° angles. How would you decide *which* line is to take as a reference for the rotation?
Also, a simple rotation will not compensate for perspective distorsion.

Instead of simply rotating a rectangle, you should probably use a transformation.

I took the liberty to change your logic behind the creation of the points (making it a bit simpler): in this way they're not children of the pixmap item, but of the scene; they can also be moved, showing immediately the result image.

[image: crop and transform example]

In the following image the perspective distorsion is better explained: I'm using a source with visible perspective, and with the transformation I'm able to make a quadrilateral into a rectangle.

[image: perspective transformation]

In this example I'm assuming that the order of the points is always top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.
If the user follows another order the result will obviously wrong, so you'll probably need to find a way to better check the positioning of the points.

```
class CropView(GraphicsView):
    Changed_view = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.point_items = []
        self.crosshair = QtGui.QPixmap(point_filename)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.pixmap_item.pixmap().isNull():
            if not self.itemAt(event.pos()) in self.point_items:
                scenePos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
                if len(self.point_items) == 4:
                    while self.point_items:
                        self.scene().removeItem(self.point_items.pop())
                if self.pixmap_item.sceneBoundingRect().contains(scenePos):
                    point_item = self.scene().addPixmap(self.crosshair)
                    point_item.setPos(scenePos)
                    point_item.setFlag(point_item.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
                    point_item.setFlag(point_item.ItemIsMovable)
                    point_item.setOffset(-self.crosshair.rect().center())
                    self.point_items.append(point_item)
                    if len(self.point_items) == 4:
                        self.crop()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        if len(self.point_items) == 4 and self.itemAt(event.pos()) in self.point_items:
            # update the rectangle if the points have been moved
            self.crop()

    def crop(self):
        points = []
        for point_item in self.point_items:
            points.append(self.pixmap_item.mapFromScene(point_item.pos()))

        # get the width and height based on the 4 points:
        # I'm assuming that the points are always in this order:
        # top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left
        # so we get the width from the longest two top and bottom lines
        # and the height from the longest left and right lines
        width = max(QtCore.QLineF(points[0], points[1]).length(), QtCore.QLineF(points[2], points[3]).length())
        height = max(QtCore.QLineF(points[1], points[2]).length(), QtCore.QLineF(points[3], points[0]).length())

        sourcePolygon = QtGui.QPolygonF(points)
        source = self.pixmap_item.pixmap()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(width, height)

        transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        rect = pixmap.rect()
        # this is the target used for the transformation
        targetPolygon = QtGui.QPolygonF([rect.topLeft(), rect.topRight(), rect.bottomRight(), rect.bottomLeft()])
        # quadToQuad is a static that sets the matrix of a transform based on two
        # four-sided polygons
        QtGui.QTransform.quadToQuad(sourcePolygon, targetPolygon, transform)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
        # smooth pixmap transform is required for better results
        painter.setRenderHints(painter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        painter.setTransform(transform)
        painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(), source)
        painter.end()

        self.Changed_view.emit(pixmap)
```

Note that I also added a line to the `set_image` function:

```
        self.setSceneRect(self.scene().sceneRect())
```

This ensures that the view's sceneRect is always adapted to the actual scene rect.
Also, you should remember to remove all point items as soon as a new image is loaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it's exactly what I'm looking for. I appreciate your response and your kindness. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Excuse me , I have used the same code but instead of using CropView(GraphicsView), I have used CropView(QtWidgets.QLabel ). However, I got an error in mousePressEvent  if not self.itemAt(event.pos()) in self.point_items: 'CropView' object has no attribute 'itemAt' . How i can solve it ?

Comment: You can't expect it to work if you subclass from another class type! If you don't use a QGraphicsView you are changing a lot of the behavior of the original example, and I can't help you if I don't know what you did. If you want that, create another question.

Comment: I want to replace both  QGraphicsView with Qlabels to be easier to manipulate different other widgets on the interface. I found my self restricted with QGridLayout which is not easy to deal with

Comment: As I said, changing the class type radically changes the approach, as you can't use the QGraphicsView features, so you'll need to create a new question for that.